# Why lambda slows down sorting

Tags: c++, lambda

Why `std::sort` performs slower with lambda function? Isn't an internal comparison function used for the case with no lambda function?

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using steady_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using time_point = steady_clock::time_point;
using milli = std::chrono::milliseconds;

int main()
{
    const int N = 1e7;

    std::random_device rnd_device;
    std::mt19937 mersenne_engine {rnd_device()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {1, N};
    auto gen = [&dist, &mersenne_engine](){
        return dist(mersenne_engine);
    };

    std::vector<int> v1(N);
    generate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), gen);
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2 = v1;

    time_point begin, end;

    // without lambda
    begin = steady_clock::now();
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    end = steady_clock::now();    
    std::cout << "elapsed v1 = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milli>(end - begin).count() <<std::endl;

    // with lambda
    begin = steady_clock::now();
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [](int left, int right){return left < right;});
    end = steady_clock::now();    
    std::cout << "elapsed v2 = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milli>(end - begin).count() <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilation options/switches?

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd35af7f0be81edd) Which compiler and flags?

Comment: OP probably forgot to include optimization. Compilers nowadays are able to inline lambda functions.

Comment: Compiler is g++ with no flags.

Comment: Make sure optimizations are turned on. clang, with no optimizations and likely therefore no inlining, will deliver 783/2205 on my puny little MBA. Cranking up release mod at -O2 results in 779/779. Your question should include the toolchain (including version) and any switches you used for compilation.

Comment: @Shibli add `-O2` and run your test again.

Comment: @Shibli Please [edit] your question to add more information (compiler flag) instead of posting as a comment.

Comment: Yes, -O2 leveled them.

Comment: @RichardCritten Remove first sentence please. (the second sentence is fine)

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry I am noob about these compiler issues.

Comment: The notion of an "internal function" is something you might come across in interpreted languages such as PHP, but in a C++ program _all_ code is in the executable, whether it was written by yourself, provided with the standard library (and thus potentially found in a linked library), or encoded using pony magic inside the compiler's source code. The end result is the same. So it's not really a consideration - code is code.

Comment: Worth also noting what happens when the likelihood of inlined comparison is tossed in the garbage due to architecture decision. Using an old-school *function-pointer* for example, will dramatically reduce or completely eliminate the chance for inline optimization. See it live [here](https://ideone.com/TftnJB) and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14eae54b5618bc28). If you're going to customize a comparator to a standard algorithm, you're doing it right: prefer a lamda or functor.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't an internal comparison function used for the case with no lambda function?

No, no internal function is used to do the comparison. It uses `operator <` directly.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

> Elements are compared using operator<.

Though a good compiler may inline the function, that is not guaranteed, specially if optimization is not turned on. While the version of `std::sort` without a function always uses `operator <`, i.e. no function call is involved here (obviously assuming that the type is not a user defined type with overloaded `operator <`).